# function generating NA in R

Tags: r

I need help, my function not work correctly when i try make any sum with the results.
have a lot of NA values and I don't know why.

```
Craps <- function(jogadas){
   for (i in 1:jogadas){
    
    comeOut <- sample(1:6,1)+ sample(1:6,1)
    
    if(comeOut %in% c(2,3,12)){
      
      result <- F #False
      
    }else if(comeOut %in% c(7,11)){
      
      
    }
    else{
      
      dados <- sample(1:6,1) + sample(1:6,1)
      
      if(dados == 7){
        result <- F
      }else {
        result <- T
      }
      while (!(dados %in% c(7,comeOut))){
        dados <- sample(1:6,1)+ sample(1:6,1)
        
      }
      if(dados == 7)
        result <- F
        
      else result <- T
     
    }
    print(result)
    #probability
    prob<-NULL
    prob[i] <- result
    prob2<-sum(prob)/jogadas
    print(prob2)
   }  
  }
Craps(1000)
```

Comment: I believe you are missing `result <- T` in the section following the line `}else if(comeOut %in% c(7,11)){`

Comment: I accidentally deleted this snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `prob=NULL` inside your loop, so it will become NULL at each iteration of the loop, just create `prob` before the loop. Also you forgot one line as noticed in the comments :

```
Craps <- function(jogadas){
  prob<-NULL
  for (i in 1:jogadas){
    
    comeOut <- sample(1:6,1)+ sample(1:6,1)
    
    if(comeOut %in% c(2,3,12)){
      
      result <- F #False
      
    }else if(comeOut %in% c(7,11)){
      result <- T
      
    }
    else{
      
      dados <- sample(1:6,1) + sample(1:6,1)
      
      if(dados == 7){
        result <- F
      }else {
        result <- T
      }
      while (!(dados %in% c(7,comeOut))){
        dados <- sample(1:6,1)+ sample(1:6,1)
        
      }
      if(dados == 7)
        result <- F
      
      else result <- T
      
    }
    print(result)
    #probability
    
    prob[i] <- result
    prob2<-sum(prob)/jogadas
    print(prob2)
  }  
}
```